# How can I access IBM Cloud Compose RabbitMQ logs?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is there a way to get [IBM Cloud Compose for RabbitMQ](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/compose/rabbitmq) logs using web interface or cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Syslog-NG](https://help.compose.com/docs/rabbitmq-add-ons#section-syslog-ng) for RabbitMQ and it has other cloud logging services namely papertrail and Loggly providing the webinterface along with two IBM Cloud Compose API calls for logs

Get list of available logfiles
GET /2016-07/deployments/:id/logfiles

Get details of a logfile including download link
GET /2016-07/deployments/:id/logfiles/:logfile_id

To make use of the API, you will need a handful of digital assets; a token for your account to access the IBM Cloud API and a foundation endpoint for your queries. Check this [link](https://www.compose.com/articles/the-ibm-cloud-compose-api/) for details on how to get the token, endpoint and example cURL calls